# How can I plot manually-calculated densities onto a map with ggmap?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geospatial, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap showing proximity of bus stops in Chicago, using Manhattan distance (L1) instead of Euclidean and an inverse-square weight, using the average daily ridership as a scaling factor.

For loading the map, I use `ggmap`

```
require(ggmap)
chicago_map = get_map(location = c(lon=-87.64,lat=41.8787),zoom=14)
```

Here is a sample to work with:

```
require(foreach)
require(geosphere)
bounding_box = bb = list(c(41.96,-87.75),c(41.80,-87.6))
meter_per_lat = distVincentyEllipsoid(rev(bb[[1]]), 
                                      rev(bb[[1]] + c(1,0)))
meter_per_lon = distVincentyEllipsoid(rev(bb[[1]]), 
                                      rev(bb[[1]] + c(0,1)))
dist_converter = c(meter_per_lon, meter_per_lat)
dist_manhattan <- function(p1, p2){
  #assume 20 meters is the smallest distance between points 
  pmax(20,abs(sweep(p2,2, p1)) %*% dist_converter)
}
set.seed(0)
sample_data = data.frame(longitude=runif(20,bb[[1]][2],bb[[2]][2]),
                         latitude =runif(20,bb[[2]][1],bb[[1]][1]),
                         mean_riders=4*rpois(20,500))
chicago_grid = expand.grid(latitude=seq(bb[[1]][1], bb[[2]][1],length.out=200), 
                           longitude=seq(bb[[1]][2],bb[[2]][2],length.out=400))
mean_values = foreach(i=1:20, .combine='+') %do% {
    row = sample_data[i,]
    dists = dist_manhattan(c(row$longitude,row$latitude), 
             as.matrix(chicago_grid[,c('longitude','latitude')]))
    return(row$mean_riders / dists^2)
```

}

```
chicago_data = chicago_grid
chicago_data$rider_weight = mean_values
```

And for the plotting, I approximate with `geom_point()`

```
ggmap(chicago_map, extent='device') + geom_point(data=chicago_data, 
        aes(x=longitude,y=latitude,color=rider_weight,alpha=0.2,shape='15',size=4)) +
      scale_alpha_identity() + scale_color_gradient(low='blue',high='red') +
      scale_size_identity() + guides(shape='none') + ggtitle('Chicago Station Example Map')
```

While you can see parts of the "heatmap" somewhat clearly, it is obviously not an optimal solution.

[image: Attempt at plot]

If I try to use `geom_tile`, I can get an okay-looking map, but it takes much longer to generate (which is not desirable)

```
ggmap(chicago_map, extent='device') + geom_tile(data=chicago_data, 
        aes(x=longitude,y=latitude,fill=rider_weight,alpha=0.6)) +
      scale_alpha_identity() + scale_fill_gradient(low='blue',high='red') +
      scale_size_identity() + guides(shape='none') + ggtitle('Chicago Station Example Map')
```

[image]

I can also replace `geom_tile` with `geom_raster`, but `geom_raster` doesn't work outside of Cartesian coordinates.  Specifically, the error is,

Error: geom_raster only works with Cartesian coordinates

Is there a better way to perform this task?

Comment: What's the problem exactly with the 2 methods you demo'ed? I guess the weird lines over the graph is the problem with the first one? and the 2nd one?

Comment: Are you plotting rider weight as blue in areas with no stations/data? If so, wouldn't it make more sense not to put any color where there's no station/data?

Comment: The second one is very slow, especially for larger maps and finer granularities. I was hoping that there was a faster way to produce interpolated graphics instead of ggplot's slow method of dealing with this.

For example, the first graph took my computer less than 1 second to generate, but the second one took about 16 seconds.

Comment: @Hack-R I will be dealing with truncating insignificant values later, but for now I would prefer to have a generalized method of plotting a heatmap over an entire region efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way with ggmap to turn your results into a raster within it

```
ggmap(chicago_map) + coord_cartesian() +geom_raster(data=chicago_data, aes(x=longitude,y=latitude,fill=rider_weight,alpha=0.2))
```

It does not look very different from the geom_tile though

Comment: This solution works well for the area I am working with. If there was a solution that would keep the spherical projection, that would be nice, but the speed improvement was the one I was looking for.

Comment: reading on ggmap I found that it only works in Mercator projection. However. there is a work around with [ggplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_map.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually transform it into a raster, in order to do that, first tranform your data frame into a spatial points object

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
coordinates(chicago_data)=~longitude+latitude
```

Give it the proper projection

```
proj4string(chicago_data)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
chicago_data = spTransform(chicago_data,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
gridded(chicago_data) = TRUE
```

And turn it into a raster

```
r = raster(chicago_data)
projection(r) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

I am not sure if you can use that in ggplot2, but you can actually plot it as a raster

```
plot(r)
```

Comment: I think you need to load the `raster` package for this. I am looking for a solution that allows the heatmap to be plotted over the original map, though.